# Google OAuth using Angular 5 with Spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am a beginner to spring as well as angular. I have a simple application built with Spring boot with Spring REST data JPA and Angular 5 as front-end. Built a basic CRUD application which stores the user's wishlist and everything is working fine. What I am trying to achieve is, user should able to login to the application using any Auth provider (Google/Facebook) and have access to only their resources.

I tried to use OAuth in my app. So, I installed and followed the instructions given in this tutorial https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login and I got the front-end working as the demo given in the link. But I have no idea how to integrate the Angular side OAuth to restrict the resource from backend(Spring app).

Any resources or idea to how can I achieve this?

**Edited**

I followed the below tutorial https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular-2-spring-boot-jwt-cors_part2/ to implement the sign-in logic within my app and it's working fine. But I have no idea how to implement social sign-in with this and how to store user information in my app.

Comment: This starter may help you : https://github.com/bfwg/angular-spring-starter

Comment: I tried that but I was not able to run the app. I tried with another tutorial for the same https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular-2-spring-boot-jwt-cors_part2/ and this works for in-app login. But no idea how to implement social login. Can you recommend any tutorial for that?